# Are there Islamic writings similar to a Christian catechism?

Tags: muslim-practices, education, comparative-religions

For major Christian faiths, *catechisms* maintained by religious authorities are relatively concise summaries of their doctrine. (One example, from the Episcopal Book of Common Prayer, can be found [here](http://anglicansonline.org/basics/catechism.html).) They are useful for launching deeper inquiry and providing basic knowledge to children, converts, and curious strangers.

Are there analogous (semi-)authoritative documents published in English by major Islamic institutions, useful for a stranger who wishes to gain basic knowledge? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catechism#Non-Christian_catechisms)'s page on catechisms mentions something called *Ilm ul-Hal*, but most of the high-ranking Google results for this term aren't in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't any normative catechisms in the world of Islam, though certain cultures have developed divergent practices one may describe as Catechesis.

For example, the [Six Kalimas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Kalimas) (six statements) and [two declarations of faith](http://www.muftisays.com/forums/12-virtues/5658-kalimah-iman-mujmal--iman-mufassal.html) would form the catechisms for South Asian Sunni Muslim communities. Kids memorize them without even understanding a bit of meanings. Outside the culture hardly any Muslims even knows of these Kalimas. A notable difference however is that unlike Christian catechisms the format is not that of short question and answers. Question style catechisms are rather part of the subject *Islamiyat* (or *Deeniyat*) taught to children in early school education. School curriculum on Islam has gradually superseded the old catechisms, which are memorized additionally by the more religious-minded people.

I'm unaware of any catechisms in other Muslim communities but I would expect elementary education for children to have some catechisms.